# Cannot import the SimpleCallback class

Tags: android, android-support-library, importerror

I want to use the SimpleCallback class from the ItemTouchHelper class as seen below, but somehow the import fails. Android Studio says "cannot resolve symbol ItemTouchHelper".

I looked into the android developer site, but I couldn't find any deprecated marker or something like that.

It seems as if it can still be used.
Android Studio is up to date (2.2.3) and the installed APIs too.

[image: SimpleCallback]

The Android Support Plugin is also activated.

[image: Android Support Plugin]

I hope someone can help me. Feel free to ask me for details.

Update: Android Studio can't find the helper class. "...widget.helper".
See below:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.
```

Comment: go to File -> Invalidate cache and restart -> Gradle sync. try atleast two times it will import if you already added library in build.gradle

Comment: I did that, but unfortunately that didn`t help

Comment: Your Android Studio plugin is not what you need. Open the Andriod SDK Manager and make sure the Support Library is installed there

Comment: I did that too. I unistalled it and installed it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "Android Support" plugin says "yes, this IDE can develop Android apps".

It is not literally the [Android Support **Library**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html).

Please see [how to set that up](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

And make sure your gradle file contains

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:(pick a version)"
}
```

Comment: I added compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1" to dependencies of build.gradle. I had to modify the minsdkversion to 9. android support library is set up in sdk manager. Problem still remains

Comment: What about other classes in there? AppCompatActivity? Recyclerview?

Comment: Thx for your help. I don´t know how, but after removing the dependency for appcompat, some restarts of Android Studio, cleaning and rebuilding of the project it worked. Android is sometimes a mysterious for me